# How can I figure out which chapter is "selected" value using web scraping with python. I want to get the selected and get the chapter and volume

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

I have this html that I am trying to scrape off a website

```
    <select class="navi-change-chapter">
        <option data-c="24">Vol.4 Chapter 24</option>
        <option data-c="23" selected>Vol.4 Chapter 23</option>
        <option data-c="22">Vol.4 Chapter 22</option>
        <option data-c="21">Vol.4 Chapter 21</option>
        <option data-c="20">Vol.4 Chapter 20</option>
        <option data-c="19">Vol.3 Chapter 19</option>
        <option data-c="18">Vol.3 Chapter 18</option>
        <option data-c="17">Vol.3 Chapter 17</option>
```

I want to be able to scrape the selected value and from that value I want the volume number and the chapter number

Answer (score 0):

You may need to edit this as I can only go off the HTML provided:

```py
# Get the <select> element. I use Tag Name for brevity.
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "select")
# Use a CSS Selector to find the option with the 'selected' attribute.
selected = dropdown.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "option[selected]")
print(selected.text)
```

This prints `Vol.4 Chapter 23`. You can then splice the text to get the information you want. You can get the chapter from the `data-c` attribute with:

```py
selected.get_attribute("data-c")
```

Using the sample data, this returns `23`.